# Avoiding the Liskov substitution principle in Scala sub-classes and polymorphism in Seqs

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have two types of Promotions: A standard promotion such as "buy one, get one free" and a short dated promotion for products which are nearing their shelf-expiry date.

The two types are somewhat stripped down here, but shows the fields:

```
case class ShortDatedPromo extends Promotion (val name, val startDate, val endDate, val wasPrice, val nowPrice, val productID)

case class RegularPromo extends Promotion (val name, val description, val terms, val productID, val date)
```

As you can see, to us humans these are both just Promotions. However, to the scala compiler they are very different beasts.

I am extending from a base class Promotion so that I can store them in a Seq[Promotion]. Maybe have 3 RegularPromos and 1 ShortDatedPromo. The idea is to then on the front page (this is a Play website) have a section for simply "Promotions".

As I understand it, if I define all the getters/setters in the super class I will break the Liskov substitution principle, because a RegularPromo can not just be swapped in place for a ShortDated Promo.

How do I then implement polymorphic dispatch while traversing a Seq[Promotion] without having to have some type checking code? Is there near trick in Scala I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: Why not make the `Promotion` abstract (or trait) with some general purpose method you need and implement it in concrete classes (as `ShortDatedPromo` or `RegularPromo`)?

Comment: sure, but the ShortDated needs a "get productShelfExpireDate" but the Regular doesn't. So the code to iterate over the Seq will try and call the function on the RegularPromo and fail....

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to have common vals defined in a base trait. So if your going to display your promotions in exactly the same way, only using those common vals, that's a acceptable solution.

If there's differences, I would pass 2 Seq, one for each type of promotion, to the template.

You could also use pattern matching to find the concrete type (in that case Promotion should probably be sealed).

A last solution is to use a HList and a polymorphic function from shapeless, it's fun but  clearly overkill given your use case.

Cheers